# Elementary os 5.1 hera stuck at boot

Tags: release-hera, boot

So I cant reach the login screen. When i boot in the system the elementary os icon shows up, it glows for a while than it completely freezes. When i pressed escape before it froze it was going through the services list then login shows up in the terminal for about 2 seconds then the screen completely clears theres just an underscore blinking in the top left of the screen.

When i looked at the boot.log there was no errors like i saw after pressing escape.BTW i can boot up with from the advanced settings with the other ones except the top one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can log into the other kernel and then try to remove quiet splash from /etc/default/grub file this way:

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

Press ins (insert) button on your keyboard to edit, remove quiet splash.
Then press Esc button and type

```
:x
```

It will save the change and exit the editor.
Then type:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Next type:

```
sudo reboot
```

To restart the machine and you will see what is going on during the boot.

Let me know what you will see on the screen. Then we can proceed with the further troubleshooting like chroot or checking logs via journalctl -b or dmesg.

Comment: i tried update-grub but it says not found but i can edit the file

Comment: Did you save the change in file? sudo update-grub must work. I do not believe that this command is not recognized.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/418666/update-grub-command-not-found

Comment: i  forgot to mention update-grub does work it doesnt find the /etc/default/grub

Comment: You did not read the link I provided in previous comment I see. There is an explanation that you can reinstall grub by typing: sudo apt update && sudo apt install --reinstall grub

Comment: Sorry for being late I solved the problem with update-grub and rebooted the computer but there really isnt anything interesting its all the same as a normal boot but there isnt anything after that.

Comment: after updating grub i think 1 more version added to the advanced menu i think it had 61 in the end and it doesnt start up like the 59 one

Comment: So install the grub customizer via ppa. You will find the tutorial in Google and remove the top one entry totally via the grub customizer. Save changes, restart